# Do you need ftp access to build/administer a wordpress account

Tags: ftp, wordpress

I just installed wordpress for a new website for our company. The person that will be building and maintaining the site asks for FTP connection data.

While I have no real reason not to give it to him (SFTP that is) I feel there should be no need for them. Am I wrong?

He says he needs them to edit the css, but I find it hard to believe that is how you should work with wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** no, he shouldn't need ftp access

**Long answer:**
If the person actually knows what they are doing, Wordpress in made in such a way, that it should only be needed to supply a proper module or template, that will then be integrated into Wordpress and then be a selectable in the menu, it's one of the great/easy of use things about Wordpress.

HOWEVER, more advanced functionality might require doing some alterations to the core of Wordpress or the like. Though in this case it just sounds like he needs to make simple CSS and html. In this case as a Wordpress developer/designer he should know how to make templates/modules and shouldn't require ftp access.

Some people might argue that development and testing is easier directly on the system, however testing and development should **NEVER** be done on a live system.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can edit all css files in css editor in wordpress.

https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/

using plugin in own server:

http://jetpack.me/support/custom-css/
are a lot of them.